# Entry points to one location from different products

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation

**The scenario**

We have one Product that contains a Candidate list in one location in our main database, with its own UI and functionality (standard list admin functionality)

We also have about six different individual internal branded websites/products under our network, but all accessing this main database

**User story:**
As a user of one of these products,  I want to be able to gain access/easily add to or create a new candidate list from any of our products UI that i am using, instead of having to log out of whatever product im currently using, and log into this candidate list to perform this action.

So in essence - Have the functionality of the candidate list but retain the look and feel of the product i'm currently using

What do you guys think would be the best approach for this? i was thinking this would could be achieved by a pop up window/Modal window and following a step through process

Or is it best to develop the UI and call an API for this?

Hope this is clear?

Answer (score 2):

yes it's partly clear :)

When a coherent database exists, the task is easier in the implementation context.

If we navigate the main interface (list function),
easily creating or adding a new list of candidates from any interface will add to the same database.

I understand that the problem in this context is switching between contexts / interfaces to perform actions?

I see two possibilities with this collection of information:

1. The API (endpoints + business logic) remains identical in the context of adding the list, so creating a separate front-end in each platform however, it repeats the code and functionality, so
2. Creating a coherent, integral list adding process that all interfaces have access to. (I would avoid a modal window in this context)